# How can I create a program which adjust screen brightness on windows?

Tags: python, pywin32

I was trying to create a simple program which automatically adjusted screen brightness on every single app window, I tried to use `PyWin32`, but it just sends the message to the operating system and there is no brightness level change!!!!!!!

I installed `pywin32` using `pip`.

worked with `win32.gui`, `win32.api` and `win32.con`

The following shows Python code:

```
import win32con, win32api, win32gui


def get_active_window_titel():
    window_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    window_title = win32gui.GetWindowText(window_handle)
    return window_title


def adjust():
    active_app = get_active_window_titel()
    if "Action center" in active_app:
        win32api.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, 
        win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 10)
    else:
        win32api.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, 
        win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 10)

while True:
    adjust()
```

Answer (score 0):

The win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER message with the 10 parameter typically corresponds to turning off the display. If you want to adjust the screen brightness, you need to use the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message with the SPI_SETSCREENBRIGHTNESS action.

```
import win32con
import win32gui
import ctypes

def get_active_window_title():
    window_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    window_title = win32gui.GetWindowText(window_handle)
    return window_title

def adjust_brightness(brightness):
    SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170
    WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A
    SPI_SETSCREENBRIGHTNESS = 0x0101

    # Set the brightness value (0 to 100)
    brightness_value = int(brightness * 65535 / 100)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetProcessDPIAware()
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageTimeoutW(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0, win32con.SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, 0)

while True:
    brightness_value = 50  # Adjust this value as needed (0 to 100)
    adjust_brightness(brightness_value)
```

Comment: it raises this error:
AttributeError: function 'SetProcessDPIAware' not found